# Как добавить форму переключатель bootstrap django

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap, веб-сайт

Учусь по книге. Хочу создать форму переключатель, но выходит обычный флажок. Не понимаю что не так, изучил много видео и форумов,но ничего дельного не нашел

### models.py

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """Тема, которую изучает пользователь"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        """Возвращает строковое представление модели."""
        return self.text
```

### forms.py

```
class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text', 'public']
        labels = {'text': ''}
        widgets = {'public': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={"class": "form-switch"})}
```

### new_topic.html

```
<form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}" method="post" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
        <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add topic</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

Выходит как то так, а нужно чтобы вместо флажка был переключатель

[image: Нужно чтобы вместо флажка Public был переключатель]

[image: Переключатель]

Comment: Какой переключатель?

Comment: Приложил скрин переключателя

Comment: А ты подключил bootstrap?

Comment: Еще ты можешь выводить каждое поле формы отдельно, и там уже как-нибудь настроить поле input (public)